# Связь двух таблиц mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, можно ли каким-то образом средствами mysql при появлении записей в одной таблице выборочно заносить их в другую. к примеру у меня есть таблица с данными о рассылке, где содержится куча смс('Индекс', 'Номер', 'Текст сообщения'). И нужна вторая таблица, которая будет содержать общие данные о рассылке('Индекс', 'Количество смс').

Comment: С помощью триггеров [Триггеры](https://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/)

Comment: @СтаниславГрот, 
`CREATE TRIGGER 'Delivery' AFTER INSERT ON 'pending'
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO delivery Set 'index' = 'pending'.'index', 'countSMS' = COUNT('pending')` что не так?

Comment: В гугле наберите "MySQL trigger" и посмотрите примеры. Как минимум тело триггера начинается на begin и заканчивается на end

Comment: @Mike, а вот и не обязателен там ни begin ни end

Comment: `INSERT INTO delivery Set 'index' = 'pending'.'index', 'countSMS' = COUNT('pending')`
Unknown column 'pending.index' in 'field list'

Comment: Ну вот так уже по делу. никакого `pending` внутри триггера нет. новые записи обозначены как `NEW`. так что используйте `NEW.index`. И count(`pending`) то же вызовет ошибку. что вы хотели посчитать этим count

Comment: Хотя что вы хотите посчитать я понял ... так вы их не посчитаете. Ибо тогда надо писать все таки `select count() from pending ...` но из триггера к самой таблице на которую триггер обращаться нельзя ... Предлагаю в триггере на insert вставлять запись с 1 в количестве, если записи еще нет. Если есть - то делать +1. В триггере на удаление делать -1 и если снизилось до 0 - то удалять

Comment: @Mike, посчитать нужно количество запсисей в таблице... но теперь я понял как это работает... как я понял, данные я смогу взять только из прошлого события `INSERT ON 'pending'`, верно?

Comment: Что такое "прошлое" ? есть триггера BEFORE, которые работают до того как запись попала в таблицу pending. И есть AFTER - которые после этого. Но особой разницы нет. В обоих триггерах у вас уже доступна `NEW` - вставляемая в данный момент запись. И триггер (for each row) будет вызван отдельно для каждой строки, так что можно смело делать +1 в счетчик. я бы предложил что то типа `insert into delivery(index, countsms) values(NEW.index, 1) on duplicate key update set countsms=countsms+1` (при наличии первичного/уникального ключа по колонке index)

Comment: @Mike, ключ установлен на другой столбец. да и нужно добавлять 1 запись... а там получается добавляется столько, сколько было в `insert`

Comment: ну раз одну - сделайте уникальный индекс

Comment: Ответ MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, countsms) values(NEW.index, 1) on duplicate key update set countSMS=count' at line 1

Comment: @АнтонБурак Надо было в последнем сообщении меня упомянуть что бы я узнал, что мне пишут ... В общем там проблема то копеечная с тем что слово index зарезервированное (не надо так колонки называть) и в итоге слово index доолжно быть в обратных апострофах. и слово set оказывается не нужно. С этими исправлениями у меня триггер создался и работает.

Comment: @АнтонБурак И что самое интересное, если begin и end не пишу - то орет что не знает колонки NEW.index. а с ними - все OK

Comment: @Mike, 
`CREATE TRIGGER 'delivery' AFTER INSERT ON 'pending'
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET @ind = NEW.'index';
  SET @sms_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'pending' WHERE 'index' = @ind);
  INSERT INTO 'delivery' SET
    'index' = @ind, 'countSMS' = @sms_count
  WHERE 'index' = @ind;
END` так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обеспечьте уникальность поля `index` в таблице pending (например, создав уникальный индекс, если это поле не primary key). После этого триггер на добавление может выглядеть так:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Delivery` AFTER INSERT ON `pending`
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   insert into delivery(`index`, countsms)
    values(NEW.`index`, 1)
       on duplicate key update countSMS=countSMS+1;
END//
```

Кроме этого вам скорее всего потребуется триггер на удаление, который будет вычитать 1 из счетчика записей.

Comment: а тригеры попадают под правила нормализации бд? (это уточнение для меня, к вопросу не имеет отношение).

Comment: @Mike, `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`

Comment: @perfect Ну сами триггера никак не оговариваются. С другой стороны, конечно, желательно, что бы они не делали такой работы как в этом триггере - т.е. ведущей к денормализации БД. С третьей стороны - подобные триггеры счетчики (и соответствующая денормализация) могут быть использованы и используются в случаях если запросов на count() очень много, а запросов на обновление - мало

Comment: @Mike спасибо я так и подумал, что это денормализация для ускорения.

Comment: @АнтонБурак Ну даже не знаю, поправил ответ на то, как написано у меня - так надо создавать из штатного средства MySQL что бы оно не запуталось с точками с запятой. В других средствах работы с БД может быть по другому !

Comment: @Mike, а что за штатные средства? я использую phpmyadmin. мне кажется у меня не получится по-другому, все эти операции провожу на хостинге, там я ограничен

Comment: @АнтонБурак Штатные - консольная утилита с названием `mysql`. А в phpmyadmin какого нибудь отдельного режима для создания триггеров нет ?

Comment: @АнтонБурак Кстати, попробовал в phpmyadmin. с вот теми DELIMITER отлично создалось

Comment: @Mike, *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '// duplicate key update countSMS=countSMS+1; END//' at line 7*

Comment: @АнтонБурак Ну это что то совсем странное. Вы delimiter в начале не забыли ? У меня в phpmyadmin тот раздел где я это делаю называется просто "SQL" вы там же

Comment: @АнтонБурак У меня там еще внизу есть поле для ввода "разделитель" можно "//" туда написать, вместо фразы DELIMITER в начале

Comment: @Mike, [image](https://s16.postimg.org/lhinbbg3p/image.png)

Comment: @АнтонБурак У меня выглядит окно точно так же, но ошибки нет. не представляю что это может быть

Comment: @АнтонБурак С какой версией MySQL Вы работаете?

Comment: @Mike, Версия сервера: 5.1.73-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: @Mike, на другом хосте сделал, все ок. Огромное вам спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Mike, еще есть один вопрос, можно ли каким-то образом получить количество записей в `NEW`?

Comment: @АнтонБурак В MySQL не бывает триггеров на несколько строк и в NEW всегда одна запись. Если вставляется несколько за раз - то триггер вызывается несколько раз  так что ни как